# Is there any limit to sell app from app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I am developing an iOS app and i want to sell that app to certain amount for example 100$ so is there any limit to sell or no limit and i want to sell products from my app so i am using in app Purchase so here also is there any limit  can any one please answer me waiting for your positive response thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store policy.

Comment: The max price for apps allowed by Apple is $999.99

Comment: can you give me any reference links

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of points apple wants you to keep in mind before you go for selling through in app purchase.

1. It should be a digital content that you give away or unlock for the user upon purchase like the full content of your app, or more levels in a game, more ammunition, subscription to the appstore etc.You can't sell like a gym membership, or any physical product using Apple's in-app purchase.
2. There are specific price tiers to which apple restricts you to sell. You can find a complete list of them here.
   https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/pricingMatrix
3. However, You can sell items by including payment gateways like ccavenue, stripe, paypal, and sell whatever you want.